# Right angle triangle and angle bisector

Tags: circles, triangles, plane-geometry

Let $\triangle ABC$ be a right-angled triangle with $\angle B = 90^\circ$. Let $\overline{AD}$ be the bisector
of $\angle A$ with $D$ on $\overline{BC}$.

Let the circumcircle of $\triangle ACD$ intersect $\overline{AB}$
again in $E$, and let the circumcircle of $\triangle ABD$ intersect $\overline{AC}$ again in
$F$.

Let $K$ be the reflection of $E$ with respect to the line $\overline{BC}$.

> Prove that $|\overline{FK}| = |\overline{BC}|$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $AB=b$ and $BC=a$.

Thus, since $AD$ is a bisector of $\Delta ABC$, we obtain:
$$\frac{BD}{DC}=\frac{AB}{AC}$$ or
$$\frac{BD}{a-BD}=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$ or
$$BD=\frac{ab}{b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.$$
Now, $$BE\cdot AB=BD\cdot BC$$ or
$$BE\cdot b=\frac{a^2b}{b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$ or
$$BE=\frac{a^2}{b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$ or
$$BE=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-b,$$ which says that $BE=FC$ and from here $BK=FC$.

Thus, since $BD=DF$ and $$\measuredangle KBD=\measuredangle CFD=90^{\circ},$$
we obtain
$$\Delta BDK\cong\Delta FDC,$$
which says $D\in KF$ and $BC=KF$.

Done!

Comment: Can you send me the figure of it

Answer (score 0):

I will show that $|FD| + |DK| = |BC|$ and that $\overline{FD}$ and $\overline{DK}$ are on the same line.

Denote $$\angle BAD = \angle DAC=\alpha$$

then $ABDF$ is cyclic quadrilateral, so $\angle BDF=180-2\alpha$, so $\angle FDC = 2\alpha$, thus the $2$ triangles

$\Delta BAC$ and $\Delta FDC$ are similar. So

$$\frac{|AC|}{|DC|}=\frac{|AB|}{|DF|}$$

but also by angle bisector theorem,

$$\frac{|AC|}{|DC|}=\frac{|AB|}{|BD|}$$

$\implies |DF|=|BD|$

$AEDF$ is also a cyclic quadrilateral
$$\Rightarrow \angle EDF = 2\alpha$$

$\Delta BDE \sim \Delta BAC$

$$\frac{|AC|}{|DE|}=\frac{|AB|}{|BD|}$$

again by angle bisector theorem,

$\implies |DE|=||DC|$

So in total,

$|FD| + |DK| = |BD| + |DC|=|BC|$

If $K$ is reflection of $E$ w.r.t. $\overline{BC}$ then

$\angle BDE=\angle BDK=2\alpha$

So the $2$ angles, $\angle FDC$ and $\angle BDK$ agree and

thus $\overline{FK}$ goes through $D$